# Изменение шрифта и заднего фона QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, qmessagebox

У меня есть код где я хочу сделать окно входа в приложение. 
Столкнулся с проблемой при изменении цвета, шрифта, цвета текста и заднего фона `QMessageBox`.

Как можно это сделать, например чтобы:

- задний фон `QMessageBox` был белым,
- шрифт "Arial",
- цвет текста ошибки например красный.

Пробовал добавлять `stylesheet`, не получилось.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from design2 import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)     

    def onClicked(self):                                                      
        
        if self.lineEdit.text() != '123' or self.lineEdit_2.text() != '1234':
                msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Error', 'Неправильный логин или пароль')
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Welcom', 'Добро пожаловать!')


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**design2.py**:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 400, 201, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:0.545, x2:1, y2:0.563, stop:0 rgba(53, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(42, 255, 177, 255));")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 261, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(100)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 290, 261, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(12)
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 181, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(35)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 360, 201, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 360, 16, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Вход"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите логин"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите пароль"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войдите"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Максимальная длина пароля - 12"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Настройте цвета, которые вам нравятся, используя параметр `setStyleSheet`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design2 import *

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)     

    def onClicked(self):                                                      
        if self.lineEdit.text() != '123' or self.lineEdit_2.text() != '1234':
#            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Error', 'Неправильный логин или пароль')
            messagebox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon,
                "Error",
                "<p style='color: white;'> Неправильный логин или пароль </p>",
                parent=None,
            )
            messagebox.move(self.pos().x()+350, self.pos().y()+200)
            messagebox.setIconPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Qt.png").scaled(100, 100, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            messagebox.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            messagebox.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QMessageBox {
                    font: italic bold 16px;
                    border: 5px solid blue;           
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    background-color: rgb(100, 1, 1);
                }         
                """
            )
            messagebox.exec_()
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Welcom', 'Добро пожаловать!')  # + None


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как изменить цвет текста?

Comment: @imapw_  `<p style='color: white;'> Неправильный логин или пароль </p>`

Comment: @imapw_ если мой ответ решил вашу проблему и вы узнали что-то новое, вы можете отметить его как полезный.

Comment: отметил, спасибо за помощь!